# Send USSD command to mobile phone connected via bluez to raspberrypi 4

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, dbus, bluez, ussd

I just start working with `ofono` and when I want to send USSD command.

when I use `initiate-ussd <modem>` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/workspace/libs/ofono/test/./initiate-ussd", line 27, in <module>
    properties = ussd.GetProperties()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 72, in _call_
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 141, in _call_
    return self._connection.call_blocking(self._named_service,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetProperties" with signature "" on interface "org.ofono.SupplementaryServices" doesn't exist
```

my `list-modems` :

```
[ /hfp/org/bluez/hci0/dev_97_E7_F5_A2_E4_0B ]
    Online = 1
    Powered = 1
    Lockdown = 0
    Emergency = 0
    Serial = 97:E7:F5:A2:E4:0B
    Interfaces = org.ofono.VoiceCallManager org.ofono.CallVolume org.ofono.Handsfree org.ofono.NetworkRegistration 
    Features = net 
    Name = Nexus 6P
    Type = hfp
    [ org.ofono.VoiceCallManager ]
        EmergencyNumbers = 118 110 08 911 000 112 999 119 
    [ org.ofono.CallVolume ]
        SpeakerVolume = 50
        MicrophoneVolume = 50
        Muted = 0
    [ org.ofono.Handsfree ]
        InbandRinging = 1
        EchoCancelingNoiseReduction = 1
        DistractedDrivingReduction = 0
        VoiceRecognition = 0
        Features = three-way-calling echo-canceling-and-noise-reduction voice-recognition release-all-held create-multiparty hf-indicators 
        BatteryChargeLevel = 5
    [ org.ofono.NetworkRegistration ]
        Status = registered
        Mode = auto-only
        Name = SomeThing
        Strength = 100
```

I'm able to make a phone call and receive it. but no USSD.

Got that I didn't have a `org.ofono.SupplementaryServices` in my Interfaces so how can I add this to my interfaces?

I'm using bluez5, ofono and i'm connecting my cell phone to raspberrypi 4.
Also I intent to send and receive SMS too. But I got the same error on `org.ofono.MessageManager`.

Thanks a lot